# Reversing logical operators causes R function to fail?

Tags: r, operators

I have a vector that is essentially a series of data points recorded over time, for example-

`data_vector <- c(5,21,25,26,67,24,15,11,15,19,27,28,22,14,11)`

I want a function that identifies the indexes when the data crosses a user defined threshold, both as the data are decreasing and increasing. To identify and output the values where the threshold (20.01 in this case) is crossed as the data are decreasing, this function does the job-

```
> x <- function(threshold){
+   crossing_points_down <- c()
+   for (i in 1:length(data_vector-1)) {
+     if ((data_vector[i] > threshold && data_vector[i+1] < threshold ) == TRUE) {
+       crossing_points_down <- append(crossing_points_down,i+1)
+     }
+   }
+   return(crossing_points_down)
+ }
> 
> x(20.01)
[1]  7 14
```

But when the logical operators are reversed to find the upward crossing points, I get this error-

```
> x <- function(threshold){
+   crossing_points_up <- c()
+   for (i in 1:length(data_vector-1)) {
+     if ((data_vector[i] < threshold && data_vector[i+1] > threshold ) == TRUE) {
+       crossing_points_up <- append(crossing_points_up,i+1)
+     }
+   }
+   return(crossing_points_up)
+ }
> 
> x(20.01)
Error in if ((data_vector[i] < threshold && data_vector[i + 1] > threshold) ==  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Any ideas why the two functions behave differently and how to fix this?

Comment: You sure you want `1:length(data_vector-1)` instead of `1:(length(data_vector)-1`?

Comment: In addition to gagolews comment: Your last "if" in function1 evaluates to `(11 > 20.01) && (NA < 20.01)` --> `FALSE && NA` --> `FALSE`. But, in function2, to `(11 < 20.01) && (NA > 20.01)` --> `TRUE && NA` --> `NA`. (The `NA` is because you access `data_vector[length(data_vector) + 1]`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have wrong parentheses:

```
for (i in 1:(length(data_vector)-1)) {
```

However, you should not use a loop for this. Here is a vectorized solution:

```
which(data_vector[-length(data_vector)] > 20.01 & 
        data_vector[-1] < 20.01) + 1
#[1]  7 14
```

Comment: Thanks, this is much more efficient. I'm still learning the ins and outs of R